# C# Listview, remove junk column

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a C# `ListView` in mode "details", which makes the headers visible. I have 2 columns only, and still there's always a third junk empty one.

Anyone familiar with how to hide that ? I'm supposed to hand in a professional application and that's the kind of stuff that I'll get killed for GUI-wise..

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That third one I believe is just the leftover space. You'll need to size the other columns to fit. See this posting:
[Adjust ListView columns to fit with WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802744/adjust-listview-columns-to-fit-with-winforms)

The key is the -2 on the last column:

```
[c#]
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SizeLastColumn(lvSample);
}

private void listView1_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SizeLastColumn((ListView) sender);
}

private void SizeLastColumn(ListView lv)
{
    lv.Columns[lv.Columns.Count - 1].Width = -2;
}
```