# Add Items vertically to a windows application List View

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I need to add items to a List View in Windows forms applications, but I need these items to be added only vertically, I tried all the View Modes, but the items keep adding bothe vertically and horizentally,

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

did you try the `Details` view? i think that only at that view mode the items are inserted vertically (line by line).

Comment: I tried the Details view, and now all the items are verticaly inserted, but they are all trimmed, only the first characters are displayed for each word, wit three dots at the end!

Comment: You just need to set the width of the column.  Apparently -1 will set it to auto size to the widest item in the column...I did not know that ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257500/c-listview-column-width-auto

Comment: Thanks NirMH and LandR, it worked perfectly, just one more thing, is there a way to make the long items wrap to a new line, instead of showing a horizontal scroll bar, Thanks

Comment: @Hassan: i'm not sure, the details view works like windows explorer, therefore if you don't wrap it yourself (calc the length of each string and chop it into two or more lines), the control supports endless horizontal bar

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a [ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx) might be better suited for what you need?

Comment: I need to insert icons next to each item, so I think a ListBox won't do

Comment: Ah - I'd probably stick with NirMH's suggestion of the Details view then.  You can set HeaderStyle to None if you don't want the column headers.

Comment: is ListBox contains built in **support for item with checkbox**?