# ListView.AddRange of custom Object using LINQ

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, linq, listview

I have a custom object like this:

```
    Dim Contacts As New List(Of Contact)

    Dim CurrentContact As Contact = New Contact With { _
        .Name = "Manolo", _
        .Country = "Spain", _
        .City = "Valencia"}

    Contacts.Add(CurrentContact)
```

The member vars are just Strings:

```
<Serializable()> _
Public Class Contact

#Region "Member Variables"

Private mId As System.Guid
Private mName As String
Private mCountry As String
Private mCity As String

#End Region

End Class
```

Now I have a **Listview** with "Details" mode set and with 3 columns like this:

```
 Name Column        |  Country Column       | City Column
 ------------------------------------------------------------------
 (Here goes Item)   | (Here goes Subitem 1) | (Here goes Subitem 2)
```

My question,
How I can use LINQ to directly cast each value in the desired column? so the result would be this:

```
 Name Column        |  Country Column       | City Column
 --------------------------------------------------------
 Manolo             |  Spain                | Valencia
 Next contact Name  |  Next contact Country | Next contact City
 Next contact Name  |  Next contact Country | Next contact City
 etc...
```

I've tried to cast the object as "***ListViewItem***", "***ListviewGroup***" and "***ListView.ListViewItemCollection***" but nothing worked, I'm doing something wrong, the exception says "*Value of type 'contact' cannot be converted to String*":

```
ListView1.Items.AddRange(Contacts.Select(Function(x) New ListViewGroup(x)).ToArray)
```

And this else throws a "*Value of type 'contact' cannot be converted to ListViewGroup*"

```
ListView1.Items.AddRange(Contacts.Select(Function(x) New ListViewItem(x)).ToArray)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it, you have to pass an array of string arrays to the AddRange function:

```
ListView1.Items.AddRange(Contacts.Select(Function(listElement) new ListViewItem(new string() { listElement.Name, listElement.Country, listElement.City })).ToArray())
```

not sure which without testing and I can't test right now.

See this question: [Populating a listview multi-column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482501/populating-a-listview-multi-column)

Comment: Thanks for answer but I did not understand, I've tried to test the code but does not work, I don't have any listviewitem already set, I need to add a range (a List(of Contact)) into an empty listview, which has 3 columns, and the object has 3 members (contact.name, contact.country, contact.city), if you need more information just tell me to update the question with the "Contact" class content, but I tell you that the class only has string properties and members. PS: Forgive my English

Comment: can you be more specific please?

Comment: @ElektroHacker - See edit.  Looked again at the documentation

Comment: Thankyou again but no way it won't work, i show you the exception message: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'AddRange' can be called with these arguments:
  Value of type '1-dimensional array of 1-dimensional array of String' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection'.