# How to add from object list to ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, class, listview

I made reading from csv to an object. I used c# windows forms. It seems everything okay but I don't understand how to put every object to a ***ListView***.
Here is my main form.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp10
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();  
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             List<Duomenys> values = File.ReadAllLines("duomenys.csv").Skip(1)
                                     .Select(Duomenys.FromCsv).ToList();              
        }           
    }
}
```

and here is my class

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApp10
{ 
    class Duomenys
    { 
        public string vardas { get; set; }
        public string adresas { get; set; }
        public string kodas { get; set; }
        public decimal suma { get; set; }
        public decimal suma2 { get; set; }

        public static Duomenys FromCsv(string csvLine)
        {
            string[] values = csvLine.Split(';');
            Duomenys info = new Duomenys();
            info.vardas = Convert.ToString(values[0]);
            info.adresas = Convert.ToString(values[1]);
            info.kodas = Convert.ToString(values[2]);
            info.suma = Convert.ToDecimal(values[3]);
            info.suma2 = Convert.ToDecimal(values[4]);
            return info;    
        }        
    }
}
```

How can I do output to **ListView** ?

Comment: [Populating a listview multi-column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11486406/10216583)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your columns to a list view

```
    listView1.Columns.Add("vardas");
    listView1.Columns.Add("adresas");
    listView1.Columns.Add("kodas");
    listView1.Columns.Add("suma");
    listView1.Columns.Add("suma2");
```

And then add your records :

```
    foreach(var c in values) 
     {
       listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new string[]{c.vardas, c.adresas , c.kodas 
          , c.suma.ToString() , suma2.ToString()}));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped :)