# System Information - Set column's width programmatically

Tags: c#, processstartinfo, system-information

In my code I launch System Information and open a .nfo file.

Here is the code:

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "msinfo32.exe",
    Arguments = "\"C:\Users\myName\Desktop\example.nfo\""
};
Process.Start(psi);
```

The problem is that the text is partially cut because it is too long. Of course, the user can grab the column header, but I would like to open the application with the appropriated width as default.

[image: The text is cut...]

I don't know how to set the column's width programmatically.

**BTW:** I see that sometimes the application's default width is different, for example I launched msinfo32.exe and here the columns are much wider:

[image: Wider columns]

Comment: @Dennis AFAIK, that's a native windows window and not a user defined one.

Comment: @user3185569: sorry, I've missed that it isn't your GUI, and you're just launching another application. I doubt that there is a way to set column width through command line.

Comment: @Dennis It is not me who asked the question, I think you need some morning coffee :)

Comment: You could try to get the needed information directly in C# and display them on your own WinForm using a ListView. Then its no problem to fit it to the content like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257500/c-sharp-listview-column-width-auto