# listView columns not filling space

Tags: c#

I have this list view in csharp and would like the columns to fill the entire space but I cannot find that property. In the DataGridView there is a property called AutoSizeColumnMode is there such a property in the listView

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257500/c-sharp-listview-column-width-auto

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# ListView Column Width Auto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257500/c-sharp-listview-column-width-auto)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
foreach (ColumnHeader column in listView1.Columns){
     column.Width = listView1.Width / listView1.Columns.Count;
}
```

Hope helps,

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks Berkay

Answer (score 4):

You can do this,

```
YourListView.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
YourListView.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
```

**EDIT**

Since you wanted the columns to be equally sized, as @berkay mentioned, you could do this,

```
foreach (ColumnHeader column in YourListView.Columns){
     column.Width = YourListView.Width / YourListView.Columns.Count;
}
```

The above code will read each column height and and divide the total width by the number of columns.

Comment: Many thanks Sajeetharan. But it does not fill the entire space. two columns to be split equally among the listView

Comment: you might have to write some code for that, check this https://nickstips.wordpress.com/2010/11/10/c-listview-dynamically-sizing-columns-to-fill-whole-control/