# Fix ListView Item size to Auto

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

Hello I have have a listView on my Winform's panel as shown in the image:

[image: Listview image]

There you see some items are going out of bounds.

Here What I have tried to Fix it.

```
ListView1.AutoSize = true;
```

And according to this solution [C# ListView Column Width Auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1257500/c-sharp-listview-column-width-auto)
I tried to fix it by using

```
ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
```

But it didn't work. I guess because its View to "list". I tried to resize its width by -2 but still same error.

It autosize is not possible on listview set to panel or because its view is set to "list". Horizontal Scrollbars also appreciated.

Comment: Are you adding a column at runtime? If that's the case, in its constructor specify `Width = -2`. Something like   `listView1.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader() { Text = "[SomeText]", TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Left, Width = -2 });`. This also works if you change the View style to Details. ScrollBars are automatic if you have set `listView1.Scrollable = true;`.

Comment: Alright will try this solution. Thank for your cooperation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
ListView1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
```